# Reading a text file in localhost (WAMP server) using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp

My problem is very simple, I think I have misused the slashes somewhere in the path.

I want to read a local file, the path to the file is stored in database which is managed by phpMyAdmin. The code that I use to read the file is below:

```
<?php
    $f = fopen($row['Article'], "r");
    while(!feof($f)){
       echo fgets($f) . "<br/>";
    }
    fclose($f);
?>
```

Originally the path I stored in the database is: `C:\wamp\www\project\database\article\article1.txt`

And it works just fine. Problem here is that, I'm using WAMP server, this means that I don't have to store an absolute path to the file, so I would store the path into my DB like this:

```
\project\database\article\article1.txt
```

But it doesn't work at all! The error it displays is "fopen failed to open stream".

This error means that the php code can't read the path I store in DB. So I tried several ways, such as:

```
\localhost\project\database\article\article1.txt
/project/database/article/article1.txt
/localhost/project/database/article/article1.txt
```

But none of them work. Same error displayed!

Can someone give me some tips to make it work? Thank you!!

Comment: Have you checked if the text file exists? I know it's silly but sometimes it can be as simple as that. `/project/database/article/article1.txt` seems like the correct path

Comment: Well I tried the path `C:\wamp\www\project\database\article\article1.txt` and the php code display the `article1.txt`. But it doesn't display when I try the path `/project/database/article/article1.txt`

Comment: have you tried `/wamp/www/project/database/article/article1.txt` and `/www/project/database/article/article1.txt`?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot use a leading slash for a Windows absolute path. You have to start with the drive letter for an absolute path (C:\..). If you want your code to be portable to another server, I would suggest storing the relative path from the web root (like /project/database/article/article1.txt) and then when you try to fopen, use a PHP constant or function to tell it where to look (e.g `fopen($path_to_webroot . $relative_path_to_file)`. Look at `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, `real_path()`, `__FILE__`, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954992/php-fopen-filename-is-it-relative-or-absolute

Answer (score 1):

Where your php file is? You can append

```
echo dir(__FILE__)
```

into your php block. I think the problem in wrong initial path (cwd).

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this problem is to look in logs where it is trying to read from

**"fopen failed to open stream"** **file-name**

read the file-name and change your code to get to the file you want to.

Hope it helps!

Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

the file open streams opens file relative to Current Working Directory so store the file location relative to the PHP file that is being executed. In any other case you can always change it by prending the path to you / file.
For example if i have my file in /var
and my script runs on /var/www/index.php
i can simply in that case prepend "../" to read file from /var